# Save in variable using Hashtag

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm not a web developer, but I would like to know if save in a variable what a user wrote as input in a web form in this way:

```
<input type="text" #hobby>
```

it's connect to angular 4 or it's the normal way to use hashtag to save something in a variable.

Sorry about that, but I didn't find any documentation about.

Thank you

Comment: It is angular thing, with hastag you can create template variables

Comment: A hashtag is a means of indicating that a term, in plain text, should be hyperlinked as a search term (on social media networks). It gets the name because it it uses a hash character to prefix it. Most things that use a hash symbol are not hashtags.

Answer (score 1):

In Angular this is called [**Template variable**](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax). With that name you can access your `input` and it's properties in the template, also you can access it in the component via `ViewChild`, `ViewChidren`

**Accessing in the template**

```
<input type="text" #hobby>
<button (click)="setHobby(hobby.value)">Set Hobby</button
```

Here I pass into the `setHobby` function the value of the input via `hobby.value`.

**Accessing in the component**

```
@ViewChild('hobby') myInput;
```

The input element with will be accessible in the component via `myInput` variable.